# Why does my program load a different screen than the one I need?

Tags: python

I am using PyGame, and on the press of a button "Shop" it is supposed to load shopScreen() which is just 2 white lines and 2 orange lines. the problem is, it immediately loads shopScreen() instead of introScreen() which is an image with the title and 2 buttons. When i comment out the shopScreen definition the program doesnt load, and when I make the action that the buttons do when clicked load the intro screen the program doesnt load. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((978, 517))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)
ticker = 0
intro = True
white = (255, 255, 255)
tbcolor = (255, 69, 0)
 
###########################MAKES BUTTONS##############################
######################################################################
######################################################################
class Button:
    """Create a button, then blit the surface in the while loop"""
   

    def __init__(self, text,  pos, font, action, bg="black", feedback=""):
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", font)
        if action == None:
          self.action = shopScreen()
        else:
          self.action = action
        if feedback == "":
            self.feedback = "text"
        else:
            self.feedback = feedback
        self.change_text(text, bg)
        self.do_function(action)

    def do_function(self, action):
        if action != None:
            self.action
 
    def change_text(self, text, bg="black"):
        """Change the text whe you click"""
        self.text = self.font.render(text, 1, pygame.Color("White"))
        self.size = self.text.get_size()
        self.surface = pygame.Surface(self.size)
        self.surface.fill(bg)
        self.surface.blit(self.text, (0, 0))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size[0], self.size[1])
 
    def show(self):
        window.blit(self.surface, (self.x, self.y))
 
    def click(self, event):
        
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                      self.do_function(self.action)
                      self.change_text(self.feedback, bg="red")
                    
###########################MAKES BUTTONS##############################
######################################################################
######################################################################


def introScreen():
  intro = True
  while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
# Sets window size and color
      white = (255, 255, 255)
      tbcolor = (255, 69, 0)
  #Calls to image
      introWall = pygame.image.load("theOne.png").convert()


      # sButton = pygame.image.load('shopButton.png')
          
      bigger = pygame.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 150)
      smaller = pygame.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 40)
      side = pygame.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 90)
      # click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        
      img1 = bigger.render('________', True, tbcolor)
      img2 = bigger.render('________', True, white)

        #buttons
        # img3 = bigger.render('________', True, tbcolor)
        # img4 = bigger.render('________', True, white)

      sidebar = side.render('|', True, tbcolor)

      title = smaller.render('Basketball Gods', True, tbcolor)
      play = smaller.render('', True, white)
      shop = smaller.render('', True, white)



        # s the object on the screen
      pygame.display.update()
      window.blit(introWall, [0, 0])





        
        
        #orange
      window.blit(img1, (250, 50))
      window.blit(img1, (250, 60))
      window.blit(img1, (250, 90))
      window.blit(img1, (250, 100))
        
        #side
      window.blit(sidebar, (240, 140))
      window.blit(sidebar, (705, 140))
        
        #white
      window.blit(img2, (250, 55))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 65))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 70))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 75))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 80))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 85))
      window.blit(img2, (250, 95))
        
        #title
      window.blit(title, (385, 160))
      window.blit(play, (310, 280))
      window.blit(shop, (580, 280))
        
        
      shopButton.click(event)
      shopButton.show()
      playButton.click(event)
      playButton.show()
        #buttons
          # window.blit(button1, (0, 0))



        # if sButton.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        #   ticker = 0
      pygame.display.flip()

def shopScreen():
  shop = True
  intro = False
  while shop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
      white = (255, 255, 255)

      tbcolor = (255, 69, 0)

      bigger = pygame.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 150)

      img3 = bigger.render('________', True, tbcolor)
      img4 = bigger.render('________', True, white)


      # pygame.display.update()
      window.blit(img3, (250, 50))
      window.blit(img3, (250, 60))
      window.blit(img4, (250, 90))
      window.blit(img4, (250, 100))
    # window.blit()

    # gameDisplay.fill(white)
      pygame.display.flip()
 
# def mainLoop():
    
#     """ The infinite loop where things happen """
#     while True:
#         for event in pygame.event.get():
#             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
#                 pygame.quit()
#         playButton.click(event)
#         playButton.show()
#         if ticker == 0:
#             introScreen()
#             playButton.click(event)
#             playButton.show()
#             shopButton.click(event)
#             shopButton.show()
#         # elif ticker == 1:
#         #     shopScreen()
#         clock.tick(30)
#         pygame.display.update()
 
 
shopButton = Button(
    "SHOP",
    (600, 300),
    font=50,
    action = shopScreen(),
    bg=(255, 69, 0),
    feedback="moving")

playButton = Button(
    "ahaha",
    (260, 300),
    font=50,
    action = shopScreen(),
    bg = (255, 69, 0),
    feedback="haha")
 
introScreen()
```

Comment: When you initialize `shopButton` you write `action = shopScreen()` but needs to be `action = shopScreen`. When you add `()` you tell python to call the function, not pass it as a parameter.

Comment: You also have the same issue inside `__init__` of the `Button` class. If action is `None` set it to `shopScreen` and not `shopScreen()`

Comment: This is a very basic python issue and has nothing to do with [tag:pygame] or [tag:game-development].